# Plot aggregate with multiple columns and multiple variables

Tags: r, max, aggregate, mean

Attempting to plot aggregate data from the following data.

```
  Person  Time Period Value  SMA2  SMA3  SMA4
   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A          1      1    14  NA    NA    NA  
 2 A          2      1     8  11    NA    NA  
 3 A          3      1    13  10.5  11.7  NA  
 4 A          4      1    12  12.5  11    11.8
 5 A          5      1    19  15.5  14.7  13  
 6 A          6      1     9  14    13.3  13.2
 7 A          7      2    14  NA    NA    NA  
 8 A          8      2     7  10.5  NA    NA  
 9 A          9      2    11   9    10.7  NA  
10 A         10      2    14  12.5  10.7  11.5
# ... with 26 more rows
```

I have used `aggregate(DataSet[,c(4,5,6,7)], by=list(DataSet$Person), na.rm = TRUE, max)` to get the following:

```
  Group.1 Value SMA2     SMA3  SMA4
1       A    20 18.0 16.66667 15.25
2       B    20 17.0 16.66667 15.00
3       C    19 18.5 14.33333 14.50
```

I'd like to plot the maxes for each SMA for Person A, B, and C on the same plot.

I would also like to be able to plot the mean of these maxes for each SMA column.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so? Or are you looking for something different?

```
df <- data.frame("Group.1"=c("A","B","C"), "Value"=c(20,20,20), 
                 "SMA2"=c(18.0, 17.0, 18.5), "SMA3" =c(16.667, 16.667, 14.333), 
                 "SMA4"=c(15.25, 15.00, 14.50))

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df.g <- df %>%
  gather(SMA, Value, -Group.1)

df.g$SMA <- factor(df.g$SMA, levels=c("Value", "SMA2", "SMA3", "SMA4"))

means <- df.g %>%
  group_by(SMA) %>%
  summarise(m=mean(Value))

ggplot(df.g, aes(x=SMA, y=Value, group=Group.1, colour=Group.1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data=means, aes(x=SMA, y=m), inherit.aes = F)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and will certainly work for me, but this is dummy data and for my real data I would have 3-5 Groups and 10 SMA values. Do you know of any other way of charting so I didn't have to manually type  out the whole data frame?   `df <- data.frame("Group.1"=c("A","B","C"), "Value"=c(20,20,20), 
                 "SMA2"=c(18.0, 17.0, 18.5), "SMA3" =c(16.667, 16.667, 14.333), 
                 "SMA4"=c(15.25, 15.00, 14.50))`

Comment: When you use aggregate with your original data frame you can store that as an object (e.g., df) and skip typing out the aggregated data frame. I just didn’t have another way of inputting your data in the format you provided it in the question.

Comment: Ahh gotchya. So i could just store `aggregate(DataSet[,c(4,5,6,7)], by=list(DataSet$Person), na.rm = TRUE, max)` as the object.